# What is the reason why the struct array subscript maximum can still be used?

Tags: c

## Please pay attention to array num.

#### e.g.

```
typedef uint32_t U32;

typedef struct  _struct1 {
    U32     a1;
    U32     a2;
} struct1;

typedef struct  _struct2 {
    U32     a1;
    U32     a2;
    U32     a3;
} struct2;

typedef union _struct {
    struct1  s1;
    struct2  s2;
} structt;

structt   s[1];

struct2  ss2[1];

int main()
{
        s[0].s2.a3 = 24;
        s[1].s2.a3 = 1;

        ss2[0].a3 = 12;
        ss2[1].a3 = 0;

        printf("Please pay attention to array num.\n");
        printf("cnt0:%d  cnt1:%d \n", s[0].s2.a3, s[1].s2.a3);
        printf("cnt0:%d  cnt1:%d \n", ss2[0].a3, ss2[1].a3);
        return 0;
}
```

#### Print

- Please pay attention to array num.
- cnt0:24  cnt1:1
- cnt0:12  cnt1:0

### Help me

- the maxnum is 1 but the array subscript can use 1
- And I can't find notes for it.
- please tell me why？

Comment: Well, it can’t. It’s a memory error. C helps you infamously little with those. None of the union or struct stuff is related – you can just define an `int a[1];` and print `a[1]`.

Comment: I am sure it's nothing about union struct

Comment: It's up to you as the programmer to make sure that the program doesn't do anything stupid, like going out of bounds of arrays. C doesn't have any bounds-checking to help you with that.

Comment: I think so，too.